# Python убрать элемент из списка по заданному символу

Tags: python, list

Всем привет, есть список

```
list1=['ab','ad','#ac','ad','ae#']
```

Как убрать элементы #ac, ae# целиком т.к. там есть #.

```
for elem in list1:
  if elem=='#':
     list1.remove(elem)
```

Так не работает.

Comment: `if '#' in elem:` но итерироваться нужно по копии списка `list.copy()`, иначе может пропустить элементы. И литералы нужно брать в кавычки, ваш список некорректный. Кроме того, нежелательно называть свою переменную `list`, используйте название `lst` либо `list_`.

Comment: `remove` не годится, он будет удалять только первое вхождение элемента.

Comment: Действительно удаляет только если # вначале и при чем если # без букв

Comment: @Алексей, так ведь нет. Если Вы сделаете как говорит CrazyElf, то всё получится. Если '#' есть в строке(elem) - в начале, с буквами или без - он всё равно удалит нужный элемент
`for elem in list1.copy():
    if '#' in elem:
        list1.remove(elem)`

Answer (score 4):

Можно сделать несколькими способами:

1. В лоб

```
i = 0
while i < len(list1):
    if '#' in list1[i]:
        list1.remove(list1[i])
    else: i += 1
```

Способ такой себе, всё таки в питоне принято задачи решать красиво, а не в лоб.

2. Использование генератора списков

```
list1 = [x for x in list1 if '#' not in x]
```

Создаёт новый список, в котором только те элементы, которые не содержат #.

3. Использование фильтров

```
list1 = list(filter(lambda x : '#' not in x, list1))
```